# selected uisegmentation control issue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a uisegmentation control with three item. i want to change the color of selected index
i am implementing

```
    segmentDate = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:newDateArray];  
    segmentDate.frame = CGRectMake(8,07,300,30);  
    segmentDate.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;  
    segmentDate.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;  
    segmentDate.tintColor=[UIColor purpleColor];  
    [segmentDate addTarget:self action:@selector(indexChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];  

    [self.view addSubview:segmentDate];  

-(IBAction) indexChanged:(id) sender  
{  
    for( int i=0;i<[segmentDate numberOfSegments];i++)  
    {  
        if (i==segmentDate.selectedSegmentIndex) {  
            [[[segmentDate subviews] objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            [[[segmentDate subviews] objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];  
        }  
}
```

the problem is the color was not setting properly.if i selecting third index the color comes in 1st index...

Comment: With as many questions and answers you've had, surely you know how to format code as `code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSInteger static compareViewsByOrigin(id sp1, id sp2, void *context)
{

```
float v1 = ((UIView *)sp1).frame.origin.x;  
float v2 = ((UIView *)sp2).frame.origin.x;  
if (v1 < v2)
    return NSOrderedAscending;
else if (v1 > v2)
    return NSOrderedDescending;
else
    return NSOrderedSame;
```

}

indexchanged method

int numSegments = [segmentDate.subviews count];

```
// Reset segment's color (non selected color)
for( int i = 0; i < numSegments; i++ ) {
    // reset color
    [[segmentDate.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:nil];
    [[segmentDate.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
}

// Sort segments from left to right
NSArray *sortedViews = [segmentDate.subviews sortedArrayUsingFunction:compareViewsByOrigin context:NULL];

// Change color of selected segment
[[sortedViews objectAtIndex:segmentDate.selectedSegmentIndex] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:((c & 0xff0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((c & 0xff00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(c & 0xff)/255.0 alpha:2.0]];

// Remove all original segments from the control
for (id view in segmentDate.subviews) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

// Append sorted and colored segments to the control
for (id view in sortedViews) {
    [segmentDate addSubview:view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it seems like you can't change directly the color of a segment. I usually use images to achieve this. Try `setImage:forSegmentAtIndex:`.

There is also a custom class you could use, never tried it yet. See : [Custom UISegmentedControl](http://matteocaldari.it/2010/05/a-uisegmentedcontrol-with-custom-color)

Comment: starting with iOS5 you can use `setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:` too. Probably easier than creating two images for each segment.